# Capybara: How to check that an element has content among many similar elements?

Tags: ruby, rspec, capybara

I need to check that some content exists on the page within a specific type of selector. For example, let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<h2>HEADLINE ONE</h2>
<h2>HEADLINE TWO</h2>
```

I know how to select only the first one on the page:

```
find('h2').should have_content('Headline Two')  # have_content is also case insensitive
```

How would I check that the content exists among all of the `h2`s on the page?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Apparently you can select elements with a given text:

```
page.should have_selector('h2', text: /#{headline}/i)
```

Note: I used a regular expression to make the text search case insensitive.